# Complex Object as Inner Class inside Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Now, I'm aware that an Inner class cannot be an Entity in Hibernate.

I'll first show my code, please refer to my question below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bags")
public class Bags extends AbstractModel {

    private String brand;
    private String condition;
    private String size;
    private Extras extras;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    private class Extras {
        private boolean box;
        private boolean authenticity_card;
        private boolean shoulder_strap;
        private boolean dustbag;
        private boolean pouch;
        private boolean padlock_and_key;
        private boolean bagcharm;
        private boolean nameTag;
        private boolean mirror;
   }
}
```

Getters and setters are ommited. My question is:

If I want to have a slightly more complex object such as Extras, in which I represent the absence or not of several accessories, would it be better to create an additional table associated with bags OR is there a way around this?

Please let me know if I was not clear or you require additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Embeddable` annotation is used to declare a class will be embedded by other entities.

```
@Embeddable
public class Extras {
        private boolean box;
        private boolean authenticity_card;
        private boolean shoulder_strap;
        private boolean dustbag;
        private boolean pouch;
        private boolean padlock_and_key;
        private boolean bagcharm;
        private boolean nameTag;
        private boolean mirror;
}
```

`@Embedded` is used to embed a type into another entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bags")
public class Bags extends AbstractModel {

    private String brand;
    private String condition;
    private String size;
    private Extras extras;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @Embedded
    private Extras extras;
}
```